# Problem after updating nvidia  driver in 12.04 from x-swat repo

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

Recently I installed Ubuntu on my new system which has a Nvidia graphics card.
After installing Ubuntu 12.04, I felt that the screen resolution was not good and though it was maybe because the Nvidia drivers were not installed, so I tried to install the driver using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

After installation I restarted my system. Upon restarting, the system hangs on a screen which displays Nvidia logo and does not proceed. Can someone help me?

Comment: what is your graphics card. post result of `lspci | grep VGA`

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why you added that repository as nvidia-current will be in the official ubuntu repo.

Anyway try hitting CTRL + ALT + F1 and that should take you to a prompt. Log in and type

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Then restart.

I had an issue the other day where by nvidia driver install was hanging and re installing it resolved the issue.